# Metal straps okay for hanging PVC pipe

Tags: plumbing

We have a PVC outlet pipe in our basement for water from the sump pump to be pumped outside. It was previously hung from the joists using white, plastic straps. Last night a few of them broke, so I replaced those with metal strapping.

After reading a bit online, I'm seeing some people say that you shouldn't use metal straps for PVC pipe since it might rub against the pipe and wear through it, so only plastic straps should be used. Any merit to this claim? Should I instead just use plastic straps?

Only went to metal so they wouldn't break again and cause a big problem if we weren't home to notice next time.

Comment: @ reverence12389. If it made you feel more comfortable maybe you can add some type of moisture proof material to cushion the areas that the PVC makes contact with the metal straps? You could try some insulation sheets for plumbing and cut them to size to line the inside of the metal straps to provide protection. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a concern unless you're immediately adjacent to a very vigorous pump or other device. Plenty of PVC pipe is mounted with metal hardware of various sorts, and I've never once seen evidence that it was wearing through enough to be a concern in many years of remodeling old homes and older homes.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other questions, the real question is about possible consequences. Depending on the layout of the piping and it's size, sump pump or house well pump, the speed of the water and the turbulence created by many 90 degree elbows and such can cause pipes to vibrate. If they are held tightly by metal straps then points of stress are created. If and when a fracture occurs, a large quantity of water can end up where you want it the least in a very short time. Before you recognize it thousands of gallons have created a new pool under your home. So, the problem is far outweighed by consequences. As a former general contractor, none of my plumbers would use metal straps or 'plumbers tape' to support pvc pipe. I preferred to use pvc hanger straps myself, but plastic 'plumbers tape' is readily available and easier to use than metal..